# SSIS - Azure Blob Storage - get list of items stored in blob-container

Tags: azure, ssis, blob, enumerator, blobstorage

I need to find out a way to extract list of items or files (e.g.pdfs) stored in blob storage. Then want to upload that list to SQL table.

Tried with SSIS 'Foreach Azure Blob Enumerator' to loop through blob-container but unable to extract filesnames

i used similar way as Foreach File Enumerator

`The program [5000] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS has exited with code 0 (0x0)`

setup Foreach Loop Container as:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and include what's the output you're getting when you did `Foreach Azure Blob Enumerator`?

Comment: This link might help you [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs]

Comment: @GauravMantri - question updated plz check